# Aggregate gradients from multiple Python processes in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

**What I am trying to do:**

I would like to spawn multiple python processes (can't use threads). Each process uses the same DNN parameters, and compute their own gradients. They send the gradients to a chief. The chief then averages all gradients and performs a global update.

**What I am having problems with:**

I've set up a distributed tensorflow system that is working. However, I can't figure out how to send the gradients to the chief. I have tried these approaches:

1. Shared Python Queue. Can't pickle a tensor.
2. Use dill instead of pickle. Worked, but 'dilling' the tensor had a huge overhead.
3. Send raw gradients (instead of a tensor) to the chief via a Queue by using the session operation:

   ```
   self.optimizer.compute_gradients(self.loss, local_vars)
   ```

   but can't figure out how to turn it back into a "grads_and_vars" style data structure.
4. Wrapping the gradient tensor into a tf.Variable and sharing it on the parameter server. This was obviously wrong, since tensorflow thew a rank error:

   ```
   ValueError: Shapes must be equal rank, but are 2 and 3
   ```

Is there a 'proper' way to do this? I could figure out something hacky: Like send all of the raw training data to the chief, and do one big gradient calculation on the chief.

I'm thinking there might be a more tensorflow-esque way to do this.